# Regex: Strip optional tags between characters using preg_replace_callback (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, xml

In PHP I am iterating through a MS Word document's XML to clean up the XML, so that I can consistently replace text in a given format with user inputted text.

The format of the "variables" in the Word document are ${variablename}

For example, **${name}** gets replaced with **John**

However, Word frequently puts stray empty XML tags between the letters of the text, so I currently have the following line to clean the XML of the Word document to remove these empty tags:

```
$xml = preg_replace_callback('/\$\{(.*?)\}/is', function ($matches) { return "\${".strip_tags($matches[1])."}"; }, $xml);
```

For example, the above line of code currently works to replace the following:

```
${user<w:t></w:t>_title}
```

with:

```
${user_title}
```

However, I am also sometimes finding stray empty XML tags between the dollar and the open brackets, e.g.:

```
$</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="00F13D11"><w:t>{user_mail}
```

I have tried a number of variations of the regex but cannot get it to work. I need the regex to strip any tags between the $ and the {, however only if they are empty and no other alphanumeric characters are between the tags.

For example, I need the statement to *not* match for the following sample:

```
$</w:t></w:r>stray word here<w:r w:rsidR="00F13D11"><w:t>{user_mail}
```

I also welcome any suggestions about how to ensure both opening and closing tags are captured, so as to not leave orphaned tags. E.g. in the above line, there are two unopened tags after the dollar sign.

Thank you in advance for any input!

Comment: Don't process XML files with bare RegEx'es. That's no good. Better use an XSLT-2.0+ processor which has RegEx functionality included and is Tag-aware by definition.

Comment: **Reopen request should be denied:** The topic of parsing XML via regex has been asked, answered, and debated to death.  The best answer is ***don't do it***.  No, this question is not a precious flower that deserves its own special answer.